# pop art images generation, flex, as3, flash

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4

My client has asked to generate pop art images for the user uploaded images, [image]

Does any one of you has done some work related to this? is this sort of work is possible in flex, flash, as3, etc,

There is one software named pop art studio, which generates such images. we have Image magic software with us, does image magic generates these sort of pop art images? i don't have much idea about Image magic.

one solution for this would have been, if these images were our images, then we would haven taken them as the separate parts of one image, and applied color transform or any other thing on those parts, and would have generated these sort of poparts displayed in the picture , but client requires this option on user uploaded images, so all this is not possible in that case.

so waiting for your answers.

Thank you

Regards

Alan

Comment: i think your best option would be to use PixelBender filters.  google around, someone may have created a "pop art" filter with PB already.  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pixelbender.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're gonna need pixel bender and you're gonna have to write it yourself, I spent about 15 minutes googling for you to no avail. Here are some tutorials on how to get started with pixel bender:

http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=83

http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=84

http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=95